# Create jobs to run on a schedule that exports a CSV

Tags: oracle, jobs

I'm really new to oracle db, can anyone help or suggest what should I do, I need to generate a csv file daily, I have created a script like this but don't know how I can create a jobs using this script.

```
SET markup csv on
SET VERIFY OFF
set feedback off
set termout off
set echo off
Column ReportDate New_Value XRptDate
Select To_char(sysdate-1,'yyyymmdd') ReportDat From Dual;

Spool D:\test\REPORTSYS_HDR_&xRptDate..csv
SELECT * FROM REPORTSYS_HDR_VW;
Spool Off
```

Answer (score 2):

One option you might want to use is **DBMS_SCHEDULER**. If you are using 12c onwards, you might use the new option EXTERNAL_SCRIPT. You have also an option for creating jobs of type SQL_SCRIPT.

Let me show you an example of EXTERNAL_SCRIPT.

I am taking two assumptions because you did not specify clearly

- Your database is running on Windows.
- You have access to the database with a user with the necessary privileges to create or manage objects in DBMS_SCHEDULER and DBMS_CREDENTIAL.

**

### Steps to create an External Job

**

1.Create the Credential for the Operating system

```
begin
DBMS_CREDENTIAL.create_credential(
    credential_name => 'NAME_WIN_CREDENTIAL',
    username        => 'youruser',
    password        => 'password',
    windows_domain  => 'yourwindowsdomain');
end;
/
```

2.Create a JOB to use the credential of type EXTERNAL_SCRIPT

```
declare
v_job     varchar2(80) := 'YOUR_JOB_NAME';
v_counter pls_integer;
BEGIN
  select count(*) into v_counter from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = v_job;
  if v_counter > 0 
  then 
      dbms_scheduler.drop_job ( job_name => v_job , force => true );
  end if;
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job
  (
    job_name             => v_job,
    job_type             => 'EXTERNAL_SCRIPT',
    job_action           => 'D:\test\REPORTSYS_HDR.cmd',
    credential_name      => 'NAME_WIN_CREDENTIAL',
    start_date           => '24-JUL-20 08.15.00 AM Europe/Warsaw',
    repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=DAILY;' -- change the frequency to your needs,
    enabled              =>  TRUE,
    auto_drop            =>  FALSE -- avoid the job to be dropped after finish 
  );
END;
/
```

3.Include your SQL script into a new cmd program called D:\test\REPORTSYS_HDR.cmd , that can be triggered by the new job.

```
%ORACLE_HOME%\bin\sqlplus -S youruser/yourpassword@yourtns @D:\test\REPORTSYS_HDR.sql
```

Comment: That's a nice example. The database job calls the script from its local D:\test path - right? If that's not possibe a simple Windows-Scheduler-Job that runs the cmd might be an alternative. It doesn't need access to the DB-Severs filesystem.

Comment: @oratom,  there are several alternatives. I've tried to offer a solution in oracle for oracle scripts. Perhaps I am bias, because I've been using a lot the API of DBMS_SCHEDULER  for building calendars and running EXTERNAL_SCRIPTS and SQL_SCRIPT job types. Thereby, I can built chains with dependencies and steps to run external programs  without any third party software :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read about creation jobs in documentation about package [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72300). You need read about procedure DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB, I think you can find what you need there.

Comment: One very good option is to make use of Oracle data sync which will help you uploading csv file in Database and will help in scheduling the job.